# Could not upload a local image file embedded into HTML as a data URI into google doc via java api

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I need upload a image file from local disk. I converted the image into base64 format, and write the html file into local disk as well, that html file can be opened in browser with image showing, but the document in google doc just an empty file, even I drag that html file into google docs the image still not there. My code is below:

```
DocsService client = new DocsService("testappv3");
client.setUserCredentials("username", "password");
File file = new File("c:/test.bmp");
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

int read;
byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buff, 0, read);
}
out.flush();

String base64 = Base64.encode(out.toByteArray());
String mimeType = DocumentListEntry.MediaType.fromFileName(file.getName()).getMimeType();
String html = "<html><body><img src=\"data:" + mimeType + ";base64," + base64 + "\"/></body></html>";


URL destFolderUrl = new URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/<FOLDER_ID>/contents");
DocumentEntry newDocument = new DocumentEntry();
newDocument.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct("test"));
newDocument.setMediaSource(new MediaByteArraySource(html.getBytes(), "text/html"));
newDocument = client.insert(destFolderUrl, newDocument);
```

Comment: Why are you uploading an image with text/html as the content-type?

Comment: beacse I embeded this image file into a html file, then upload the html file into google doc. A row image file cannot be uploaded into google doc

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug, we are trying to fix it, and I will get back to you when we have a fix.

Thanks for your patience.