# Fetch images using Google Docs List API

Tags: jpeg, google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I'm using Google Docs List API for fetching documents such as .doc, .txt and even spreadsheets. Now I want to fetch any kind of uploaded file too, like .jpeg images. I've tried the same methods used for docs with no success.

Anyone had experience with this issue?

Comment: seems get the same issue with me, please have a look [this][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380266/could-not-upload-a-local-image-file-embedded-into-html-as-a-data-uri-into-google/10604657#10604657

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDocs List API works well with any type of file getting a list of the them from a collection. Just use the API for feeds without specifying the type of files you are fetching. This was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Google Docs List API only is able to retrieve documents that are in Google format. If you want to retrieve a jpeg image, probably you need try Google Drive API.

Comment: Nop. GDocs API talks explicitly about feching any type of file saved on GDocs.

Comment: But actually, you should use the Drive API, since it has replaced the Google Documents List API.